# Can't call grubx64.efi using startup.nsh in EFI

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, efi

I installed Deepin 2014.3 on VirtualBox.

When I launched it I got the regular `skip startup.nsh` message with the counter and the prompt right after it.

My `grubx64.efi` resides under `FS0:\EFI\Deepin 2014.3\`, when I tried to call it directly using absolute path it didn't work so I tried putting it in `startup.nsh`, same result, called it with single and double quotes on both sides, tried escaping the space, still not working.

What can I do in a case where the directory name has space in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, All I had to do is to add the storage device by name and double quotes to handle the space character.

Full procedure:

- `edit FS0:\startup.nsh`
- `"FS0:\EFI\Deepin 2014.3\grubx64.efi"`
- < ctrl+s >
- Enter
- < ctrl+q >
- `reset`
- Watch the magic happens.

Comment: What if one day the `FS0` changed to `FS1` due to new hardware installed?  Relative paths solution is better whenever possible.